# Trim white space and return errors in c#

Tags: c#, vs-community-edition

I'm moving from PHP (procedural) to C# and I've a number of errors in the following block - what am I doing wrong?

Objective is to pass in username and password values, then to trim, validate and return a list of errors (I'm using the dictionary to build an array of errors).

1. "The name 'varUserName' does not exist in the current context".
2. "else" = "Type or namespace definition, or end of file expected".

   ```
   public class Login (string InUserName, string InUserPass)
   {
       string varUserName;
       string varUserPass;

       // Dictionary object is c# equivalent of PHP's 'array["key"] = "value"'
       Dictionary<string, string> errMsg = new Dictionary<string, string>();

       varUserName = "123qwe";

       varUserName = varUserName.Trim();

       if ((varUserPass == "") && (varUserName == ""))
       {
           errMsg.Add("Username", "Username cannot be blank");
           errMsg.Add("Password", "Username cannot be blank");
       }
       else
       {
           if (varUserName == "")
           {
               errMsg.Add("Username", "Username cannot be blank");
           }

           if (varUserPass == "")
           {
               errMsg.Add("Password", "Password cannot be blank");
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Thanks Newbie Matt

Comment: remove keyword _class_ from your Login method signature and instead use `Dictionary<string, string>` as the return type. Also remember to return errMsg;

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you do everything in your class. You can't do logic in your class. Put your code in a Method. Like so:

```
public class Login 
{
    string varUserName;
    string varUserPass;

    // Dictionary object is c# equivalent of PHP's 'array["key"] = "value"'
    Dictionary<string, string> errMsg = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public Dictionary<string, string> LogMeIn()
    {
        varUserName = "123qwe";

        varUserName = varUserName.Trim();

        if ((varUserPass == "") && (varUserName == ""))
        {
            errMsg.Add("Username", "Username cannot be blank");
            errMsg.Add("Password", "Username cannot be blank");
        }
        else
        {
            if (varUserName == "")
            {
                errMsg.Add("Username", "Username cannot be blank");
            }

            if (varUserPass == "")
            {
                errMsg.Add("Password", "Password cannot be blank");
            }
        }
    return errMsg;
    }    

}
```

You can then call it like that in your code:

```
Login login = new Login();
var errMsg = login.LogMeIn();
```